# Geting started with contiki 2.7

Tags: contiki

I am really new in Contiki OS. I downloaded contiki 2.7 zip from sourceforge. To understand how the system works I first need to understand the make system that is used for building projects. In almost every location inside the contiki there is a make file. So the syntax used in those files is completely alien for me. My question is: What/where do I need to read about these make files in order to understand how to use them? Some links would be very useful. Please have in mind that I am new in this matter.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

u can start with this link about the Contiki build system
http://dak664.github.io/contiki-doxygen/a01670.html